# how to get a more efficient haskell solution

Tags: haskell

I've been trying to solve this problem over at kattis problems: https://open.kattis.com/problems/rijeci
I have the solution below, but the system rejects my solution because it takes too long to complete larger inputs, I was wondering if there is a way to solve this problem more efficiently. Please don't assume I know about certain methods and such because I'm just starting out learning haskell, and functional programming for that matter.

My Solution

```
convertString :: String -> String
convertString [] = []
convertString (x:xs)
  | x == 'A'  = 'B': convertString xs
  | otherwise = 'B':'A':convertString xs

finalString :: String -> Integer -> String
finalString letters numOfTimes
  | numOfTimes > 0   = finalString (convertString letters) (numOfTimes-1)
  | otherwise = letters

getNumA :: String -> Int
getNumB :: String -> Int

getNumA = length . filter(=='A')
getNumB = length . filter(=='B')

main = do
  inputLine <- getLine
  let numOfTimes = read (inputLine) :: Integer
  let convertedString = (finalString "A" numOfTimes)
  putStrLn ((show (getNumA convertedString)) ++ " " ++(show (getNumB convertedString)))
```

Comment: You may want to use `numOfTimes <- readLn` as a shorthand for chaining `read` with `getLine`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is not in Haskell and not in the way how you treat `String` type. The problem is in **using** `String` type. This problem can solved efficiently w/o strings. Just write answers for `K` from *1* to *10*:

```
K = 1: 0, 1
K = 2: 1, 1
K = 3: 1, 2
K = 4: 2, 3
K = 5: 3, 5
K = 6: 5, 8
K = 7: 8, 13
K = 8: 13, 21
K = 9: 21, 34
K = 10: 34, 55
```

So the answer is two consecutive numbers in this sequence:

```
0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, ...
```

Does this sequence of numbers look familiar to you? ;)

There're a lot of solutions in Haskell for calculating this sequence fast.

Comment: This is a good starting-point, but I would advise programmers to be able to prove that a method works. There can be a lot of patterns that hold for the first few test cases, then break.

Comment: @Davislor it's obvious. Though by inspecting sequence of results you can have some guesses which will help you construct proof.

Comment: A lot of things that are obvious aren’t true. But the proof I give in my answer is indeed short and elementary.

Comment: @Davislor Sorry, I wasn't clear enough. By saying «it's obvious» I didn't mean the fact from problem in answer, I was saying about your statement: It's obvious that if you want to be ensure in some things you should prove them and not make heuristic guesses. I like your proof and upvoted it. Just saying that it may be easier to invent proof if you first see at sequence of numbers.

Comment: @Shersh Okay, then we agree. I appreciate that you’re trying to give hints here, not a complete solution.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, let’s see if we can eliminate all the window-dressing and express this in terms of primitive recursion.  We only care about the number of A’s and B’s: their order is irrelevant to the problem.  Furthermore, the number of A’s and B’s after each push depends only on the number of A’s and B’s there were before.  So let’s call the number of A’s at step *n* *a*(*n*) and the number of B’s at step *n* *b*(*n*).

Our base case is *a*(0) = 1, *b*(0) = 0.

After a push of the button, every A in the previous string gets turned into a B, and every B gets turned into BA.  So, every A in the new string is the result of a B→AB substitution, and every letter of the old string adds one B to the new string.

This means that, when *n* > 0, *a*(*n*) = *b*(*n*-1) and *b*(*n*) = *a*(*n*-1) + *b*(*n*-1).  Now, for *n* > 1, we can substitute *a*(*n*-1) = *b*(*n*-2).  This gives us:

*a*(0) = 1, *b*(0) = 0

*a*(1) = 0, *b*(1) = 1

*a*(*n*) = *b*(*n*-1), *b*(*n*) = *b*(*n*-2) + *b*(*n*-1) | *n* > 1

Does that definition of *b*—zero, then one, then the sum of the previous two values of *b*—remind you of any other sequence of numbers you’ve encountered in a programming class?

Answer (score 0):

The trick to solving this problem has nothing to do with Haskell and everything to do with the format of the answer.

The difficulty of the problem is that the size of the string roughly doubles each iteration. All the `'B'`s get doubled to `"BA"` and all the `'A'`s get turned into `'B'`s to eventually be doubled. Building this string in memory for large numbers is intractable. To solve the problem quickly you'll need to find a way to avoid building the string in memory. This is possible because the answer doesn't ask for the string, it asks for only two numbers: the number of letters `'A'` and the number of letters `'B'`.

Before performing any steps the string consists of `1` `'A'` and `0` `'B'`s. Can you figure out from that how many `'A'`s  and `'B'`s there are after the first step?

Answer (score 0):

You can think this problem from a more mathematical side: If you have (number of As, number of Bs), the next you push the button, you will get (number of Bs, number of As + number of Bs).

You can write this down in Haskell as:

```
step :: (Integer, Integer) -> (Integer,Integer)  
step (a,b) = (b,b+a)

applyStep :: Int -> (Integer, Integer) -> (Integer,Integer)
applyStep 0 (a,b) = (a,b)
applyStep n (a,b) = applyStep (n-1) (step (a,b))
```